# Is it possible to recover a deleted form on Cognito?

Tags: cognito-forms, data-recovery

I have deleted a Cognito form by accident. Does that mean I cannot retrieve a deleted form once the delete button has been pressed?

Comment: Please only put one question in your question post. If you have another question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

We, [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), archive forms (but definitely not entries) each night in order to provide assistance to customers that have accidentally deleted forms they spent hours or days perfecting.  Please submit a help request specifying the name of the form you are trying to recover and we will see if we can help!

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support